# Add replica set to already running mongo shard cluster

Tags: mongodb, sharding, replicaset

Hi All i have set up a mongo cluster using thsi configuration

1. I have 3 different machines with mongos running on them (all are physical machines with different IPs to ensure stability/ performance/ availability ).
2. 3 config servers on 3 diffrent VMs.
3. Two Mongo shards running on high end machine( Two mongod instance running on two ports both mongod has separate db directories).

This set is in place and already running.

I want to add replica set to these two shard now means each shard will have two replica.
My question is

1. How can i add replica set to existing cluster when each shard is
   already
2. Each Replica will carry the same db space as its corresponding shard
   having almost 2 TB data with them?
3. Should i use different machine to host these replica to ensure fail over?

Answer (score 1):

> How can i add replica set to existing cluster when each shard is already

Have you read the documentation on sharding tutorials?

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/sharded-clusters/

> Each Replica will carry the same db space as its corresponding shard having almost 2 TB data with them?

Not sure what you mean, if you mean it will replicate the data on the other two shards then no. It will hold as much as it balanced out to it.

> Should i use different machine to host these replica to ensure fail over?

If you are using the same machine for your replicas then why have a sharded replica cluster?

The whole point of the sharded replica cluster setup is to distribute workload amoung many servers in a cluster.

Using the same server for it all kinda defeats the point...

That goes for using a single server for a replica set too, no point really...

Comment: Hi @Sammaye Thanks for pointing out these potential issues with system.  I went through the link you provided and it seems that sharded cluster with replica set has two replica sets created on separate machines and added as two shards.  So could you help me how can add replica to my existing set up and i will get one more machine to add new shard rather than running two shards on one machine.  Here My issue lies that as i alrrady have 3 t data on one shard so how this shard will be updated to 3 member replica set

Comment: @viren there is a tutorial near the end http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-shards-to-shard-cluster/ which goes through the steps you need to do once you hacve your replica ready to add. As for updating the existing shard, I would restart it as a single member replica set (after copying it to another machine) and then readd it with its currently existing data (pre-populated shard) and let it balance, after add the secondaries to the set.